# how do I make custom icons for folders appear on the desktop

Tags: customization

Hello I was wonder if it is possible to have a custom folder icon that appears in both the desktop and in nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can tweak your folders. I had to read twice to understand it.
First go to your desktop, right mouseclick. Select "New Folder" and create it.
Then right click on your folder icon, select "Properties" from the context menu.
You will get a dialog.
Click on the icon:

[image]

Select the icon you like.
Now my desktop folder looks like this (note that it is also seen in Nautilus/Files)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still a little bit confused, about how to create it is there a specif way that i need to name to folder  Just to clarify this allows me to create custom "folders" that show up on the desktop.

Comment: I've revamped my answer - i missunderstood your question first.